# How to install a USB TV tuner?

Tags: usb, tv-tuner, dvb

I have a USB TV tuner from [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Freeshipping-2014-Mini-USB-DVB-T2-with-PVR-USB-Set-Top-TV-Boxgood-dvb-t2-MP3/1479924002.html).

It works fine with Windows, but Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't seem to recognise it...

When typing `lsusb` in the terminal I'm getting the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 15f4:0131 HanfTek 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2101 Broadcom Corp. BCM2045 Bluetooth
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have as the link you provided does not give a lot of technical detail...

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.      I have edited the post what i am getting.  I am new to linux. Cheers

Comment: i have also found this : http://blog.palosaari.fi/2013/10/naked-hardware-14-dvb-t2-usb-tv-stick.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're halfway there already!

You did the right thing by doing an `lsusb` as that gives you the unique vendor ID for your device.

From the ID `15f4:0131` you posted, we can infer it's an [Astrometa_DVB-T2](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Astrometa_DVB-T2).

Then you head to [LinuxTV.org](http://www.linuxtv.org), which has the best resources on the web for everything Linux and TVs.

Unfortunately, the same identical ID (which *should* be unique, *but in this case isn't*) comes with 2 demodulators:

- the 2013 revision comes with a Panasonic MN88472
- the 2014 revision comes with a Panasonic MN88473

So read [this](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/What_is_V4L_or_DVB%3F) first so you know what you're dealing with (DVB) and then go on to [there](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers) to actually build the drivers yourself<sup>¹</sup>.

<sub>As the information there is too long to paste here for your device, that's the best I can do for you.</sub>

<sup>¹</sup>**Building your own drivers is not for the faint at heart!** You need to have basic programming skills and know what a compiler, linker (and in this case) firmware is!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. And sorry i saw it late. I will try to follow you instructions although i lack at programing skills. About the device - it is realy the dvb-c feature that i need to get it to work. Thanks again, and feel free to help me with other ideas. Cheers

Comment: Don't thank me! **:P**  Just click the grey  ☑ turning into a beautiful green and that's all the thanks I need! **:-)**